# WPF Is possible to map Escape key in theme style

Tags: c#, wpf, escaping, keydown

I have searched SO and got the following code working for individual forms.

```
this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(HandleEsc);

private void HandleEsc(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Escape) 
    { 
        this.Close(); 
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have to code the same on each and every WPF form in my app. I am looking for a way to put this in the theme style so that I can avoid repeated coding. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks,

Comment: if it's needed in ALL form then you can try to use EventManager.RegisterClassHandler when the app start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this can be done using styles. What you can do though, is create a new layer between your Window and the `Window` class, and have that intermediate layer take care of handling the Escape key. To do this, first create a new class called `EscapeWindow` and have it inherit from `Window` like this:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class EscapeWindow : Window
    {
        public EscapeWindow()
            : base()
        {
            this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(HandleEsc);
        }

        private void HandleEsc(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Escape) { this.Close(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Now every time you create a new Window, you can have it inherit from this `EscapeWindow` instead of `Window`. For example your `MainWindow` would look like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : EscapeWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Note that since WPF Windows are partially defined in XAML, you need to also change that partial implementation. In this case, `MainWindow.xaml` would look like this:

```
<local:EscapeWindow x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</local:EscapeWindow>
```

This might not necessarily make your life easier since you need to change the references every time you create a `Window`, but provides a clean framework for generically handling the `Escape` button.